# Fluent Nhibernate : Map one class to two identical tables but with different table names

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I need to map one entity to two tables (table x and table y). It's not up to me to merge the two database tables in one and add a discriminating column to differentiate them.

The two tables have the exact same structure, but, names of these two tables in database are different.

What should be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, from memory this could work with FNH:

```
public class A 
{
  public virtual Guid id;
  public virtual string name;
}

public class B : A { }


public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
  public AMap()
  {
    Table("Atable");
    Id(x => x.id);
    Map(x => x.name);
  }
}

public class BMap : SubclassMap<B>
{
  public BMap()
  {
    Table("Btable");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response kayess. I would give you +1 for the response. The approach that i have taken is quite similar except  that I have created a Baseclass and inherited both A and B from BaseClass.